# "had a fall" vs "fell"

Tags: phrases

I wrote, today, that I "had a fall".

A friend asked "at what age does falling over become 'had a fall'?"

I have to admit that it does seem to be an age thing, but I would like to know if there is some concensus or definition around this?

What would you see as the difference in meaning and appropriate use for

'Yesterday I had a fall, and... '.

'Yesterday I fell over, and ...'.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a sort of distancing. A fall befell me.

Comment: "Had a fall" does seem to be used mostly of older people. I suppose younger folks fall _off_ or _over_ something, while a frail older person may fall just because their legs are weak or unsteady. I doubt if there is any formal cut-off point!

Comment: I'm sure Jack is largely correct. There does come an age when falls are less due to carelessness or foolhardiness or greater exposure to risk, more because of newer and often unavoidable internal factors.

Comment: Also relates to the effects as well as the cause: for a healthy young person, falling over is trivial and easily brushed off (get up and go on), while for an old person with weaker bones, less mobility, or other health problems it's more likely to cause a lasting injury or require help just to get up.

Comment: "to have a fall" is sometimes associated with age but not always. He had a bad fall off his surfboard and blew his ACL. He had a bad fall skiing and broke his leg.

Comment: Great examples of non-age-based use, thanks.   Any insight into what drives the choice of phrase?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you think it might be connected with the use of have/had in connection with medical conditions?  as in he had a great attack, she had  a bad bout of flu' and so on?  Falling in old age is much more serious than for younger folk, because of the brittleness of bones and because the damage is much slower to heal.

Comment: @Tuffy. Possibly ... these things are hard to trace. 'Have' is used in many deverbal expressions, not just wrt ailments (have a shock / ball / good time / windfall / break [from work] / walk in the park / bath ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, and they have in common that they describe something happening to the 'haver'.  Thank you for not pointing out my 'great' (vid. 'heart') attack.